# How to pull "market capitalization” data from Yahoo! Finance within Excel?

Tags: excel, finance

How to pull "market capitalization” data from Yahoo! Finance within Excel?

i get #value error...  i get the same error when i try to get j1, j3 or r1.[See attached error and formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6x0wN.png)

Comment: did you get the formula to work for other data, but just not the j1, j3, or r1 parameters, or it doesn't work for anything?  mac doesn't have webservice for excel so i can't test it, tsk...

Comment: The data being returned for each parameter includes a line feed (ASCII code 10) at the end of each string.  So the line feed first needs to be removed from the string using the CLEAN function.  Then, for each of the parameters, the formulas will return 132.48B, N/A, and "5/18/2017", respectively.  For the first two, the formula will need to be amended according to type/variation of data.  For the last one, you can simply add the SUBSTITUTE function to remove the quotes.

Comment: Thanks Domenic.. great appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your formula was using numbervalue to convert text to a number, but market capitalization includes a B at the end of the number so it couldn't convert that to a number.  Any data that is text just simply remove the numbervalue function and leave only the webservice function.